# How to color lines on mouseover in a bump chart using Altair Viz?

Tags: python, visualization, altair

The goal is to *highlight the entire line when hovering anywhere* (not just at the data points) on the line.

Imports:

```
from IPython.display import display
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
```

Data:

```
data = '{"Date":{"5":1560643200000,"18":1560643200000,"22":1560643200000,"24":1560643200000,"59":1560643200000,"65":1561248000000,"78":1561248000000,"82":1561248000000,"84":1561248000000,"119":1561248000000,"125":1561852800000,"138":1561852800000,"142":1561852800000,"144":1561852800000,"179":1561852800000,"185":1562457600000,"198":1562457600000,"202":1562457600000,"204":1562457600000,"239":1562457600000,"245":1563062400000,"258":1563062400000,"262":1563062400000,"264":1563062400000,"299":1563062400000,"305":1563667200000,"318":1563667200000,"322":1563667200000,"324":1563667200000,"359":1563667200000,"365":1564272000000,"378":1564272000000,"382":1564272000000,"384":1564272000000,"419":1564272000000,"425":1564876800000,"438":1564876800000,"442":1564876800000,"444":1564876800000,"479":1564876800000,"485":1565481600000,"498":1565481600000,"502":1565481600000,"504":1565481600000,"539":1565481600000,"545":1566086400000,"558":1566086400000,"562":1566086400000,"564":1566086400000,"599":1566086400000,"605":1566691200000,"618":1566691200000,"622":1566691200000,"624":1566691200000,"659":1566691200000,"665":1567296000000,"678":1567296000000,"682":1567296000000,"684":1567296000000,"719":1567296000000,"725":1567900800000,"738":1567900800000,"742":1567900800000,"744":1567900800000,"779":1567900800000,"785":1568505600000,"798":1568505600000,"802":1568505600000,"804":1568505600000,"839":1568505600000,"845":1569110400000,"858":1569110400000,"862":1569110400000,"864":1569110400000,"899":1569110400000,"905":1569715200000,"918":1569715200000,"922":1569715200000,"924":1569715200000,"959":1569715200000,"965":1570320000000,"978":1570320000000,"982":1570320000000,"984":1570320000000,"1019":1570320000000,"1025":1570924800000,"1038":1570924800000,"1042":1570924800000,"1044":1570924800000,"1079":1570924800000,"1085":1571529600000,"1098":1571529600000,"1102":1571529600000,"1104":1571529600000,"1139":1571529600000,"1145":1572134400000,"1158":1572134400000,"1162":1572134400000,"1164":1572134400000,"1199":1572134400000,"1205":1572739200000,"1218":1572739200000,"1222":1572739200000,"1224":1572739200000,"1259":1572739200000,"1265":1573344000000,"1278":1573344000000,"1282":1573344000000,"1284":1573344000000,"1319":1573344000000,"1325":1573948800000,"1338":1573948800000,"1342":1573948800000,"1344":1573948800000,"1379":1573948800000,"1385":1574553600000,"1398":1574553600000,"1402":1574553600000,"1404":1574553600000,"1439":1574553600000,"1445":1575158400000,"1458":1575158400000,"1462":1575158400000,"1464":1575158400000,"1499":1575158400000,"1505":1575763200000,"1518":1575763200000,"1522":1575763200000,"1524":1575763200000,"1559":1575763200000,"1565":1576368000000,"1578":1576368000000,"1582":1576368000000,"1584":1576368000000,"1619":1576368000000},"Store":{"5":"store1","18":"store2","22":"store3","24":"store4","59":"store5","65":"store1","78":"store2","82":"store3","84":"store4","119":"store5","125":"store1","138":"store2","142":"store3","144":"store4","179":"store5","185":"store1","198":"store2","202":"store3","204":"store4","239":"store5","245":"store1","258":"store2","262":"store3","264":"store4","299":"store5","305":"store1","318":"store2","322":"store3","324":"store4","359":"store5","365":"store1","378":"store2","382":"store3","384":"store4","419":"store5","425":"store1","438":"store2","442":"store3","444":"store4","479":"store5","485":"store1","498":"store2","502":"store3","504":"store4","539":"store5","545":"store1","558":"store2","562":"store3","564":"store4","599":"store5","605":"store1","618":"store2","622":"store3","624":"store4","659":"store5","665":"store1","678":"store2","682":"store3","684":"store4","719":"store5","725":"store1","738":"store2","742":"store3","744":"store4","779":"store5","785":"store1","798":"store2","802":"store3","804":"store4","839":"store5","845":"store1","858":"store2","862":"store3","864":"store4","899":"store5","905":"store1","918":"store2","922":"store3","924":"store4","959":"store5","965":"store1","978":"store2","982":"store3","984":"store4","1019":"store5","1025":"store1","1038":"store2","1042":"store3","1044":"store4","1079":"store5","1085":"store1","1098":"store2","1102":"store3","1104":"store4","1139":"store5","1145":"store1","1158":"store2","1162":"store3","1164":"store4","1199":"store5","1205":"store1","1218":"store2","1222":"store3","1224":"store4","1259":"store5","1265":"store1","1278":"store2","1282":"store3","1284":"store4","1319":"store5","1325":"store1","1338":"store2","1342":"store3","1344":"store4","1379":"store5","1385":"store1","1398":"store2","1402":"store3","1404":"store4","1439":"store5","1445":"store1","1458":"store2","1462":"store3","1464":"store4","1499":"store5","1505":"store1","1518":"store2","1522":"store3","1524":"store4","1559":"store5","1565":"store1","1578":"store2","1582":"store3","1584":"store4","1619":"store5"},"Rank":{"5":1.0,"18":1.0,"22":1.0,"24":1.0,"59":1.0,"65":2.0,"78":2.0,"82":2.0,"84":2.0,"119":2.0,"125":2.0,"138":2.0,"142":2.0,"144":2.0,"179":2.0,"185":2.0,"198":2.0,"202":2.0,"204":2.0,"239":2.0,"245":2.0,"258":2.0,"262":2.0,"264":2.0,"299":2.0,"305":2.0,"318":2.0,"322":2.0,"324":2.0,"359":2.0,"365":2.0,"378":2.0,"382":2.0,"384":1.0,"419":2.0,"425":3.0,"438":1.0,"442":3.0,"444":2.0,"479":3.0,"485":4.0,"498":1.0,"502":4.0,"504":3.0,"539":4.0,"545":4.0,"558":1.0,"562":3.0,"564":3.0,"599":4.0,"605":5.0,"618":1.0,"622":2.0,"624":4.0,"659":5.0,"665":6.0,"678":1.0,"682":2.0,"684":5.0,"719":6.0,"725":7.0,"738":1.0,"742":2.0,"744":5.0,"779":7.0,"785":8.0,"798":1.0,"802":2.0,"804":6.0,"839":8.0,"845":8.0,"858":1.0,"862":2.0,"864":5.0,"899":8.0,"905":8.0,"918":1.0,"922":2.0,"924":4.0,"959":8.0,"965":8.0,"978":1.0,"982":2.0,"984":4.0,"1019":8.0,"1025":10.0,"1038":1.0,"1042":2.0,"1044":5.0,"1079":10.0,"1085":10.0,"1098":1.0,"1102":2.0,"1104":5.0,"1139":10.0,"1145":11.0,"1158":1.0,"1162":2.0,"1164":5.0,"1199":11.0,"1205":12.0,"1218":1.0,"1222":2.0,"1224":6.0,"1259":12.0,"1265":13.0,"1278":2.0,"1282":1.0,"1284":7.0,"1319":13.0,"1325":13.0,"1338":2.0,"1342":1.0,"1344":6.0,"1379":13.0,"1385":14.0,"1398":2.0,"1402":1.0,"1404":6.0,"1439":14.0,"1445":3.0,"1458":2.0,"1462":1.0,"1464":6.0,"1499":8.0,"1505":3.0,"1518":2.0,"1522":1.0,"1524":6.0,"1559":4.0,"1565":3.0,"1578":2.0,"1582":1.0,"1584":8.0,"1619":5.0}}'
```

Dataframe:

```
df_slim = pd.read_json(data)
```

Chart:

```
highlight = alt.selection(type='single', on='mouseover',
                          fields=['Store'], nearest=True, empty="none")

chart = alt.Chart(df_slim).mark_line().encode(
        x='Date',
        y='Rank',
        #color='Store',
        strokeDash='Store',
        color=alt.condition(highlight, 'Store', alt.value("lightgray")),
        tooltip=['Rank','Store']
    ).properties(
            width=800,
            height=600,
            title='Bump Chart: Store Ranking'
            ).configure_title(
                fontSize=30,
                font='Courier',
                anchor='start',
                color='gray'
            ).add_selection(
    highlight
)
display(chart)
```

Output:

[image]

Any help? Not sure what went wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question! It turns out this is one of the current limitations of Vega-Lite. I found this note in the VL docs on [Nearest Value](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/nearest.html)

> The nearest transform is not supported for continuous mark types (i.e., `line` and `area`). For these mark types, consider layering a discrete mark type (e.g., `point`) with a 0-value `opacity`

So for your example I would do something like this

```py
highlight = alt.selection(type='single', on='mouseover',
                          fields=['Store'], nearest=True, empty="none")

chart = alt.Chart(df_slim).mark_line().encode(
        x='Date',
        y='Rank',
        #color='Store',
        strokeDash='Store',
        color=alt.condition(highlight, 'Store', alt.value("lightgray")),
        tooltip=['Rank','Store']
    )

points = alt.Chart(df_slim).mark_point(opacity=0).encode(
        x='Date',
        y='Rank',).add_selection(
    highlight
)

chart + points
```